# XenCenter cannot connect to XenServer

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, xen

I am trying to establish a connection using XenCenter 6.0 to a server where XenServer 6.0 is installed, but it gives me the following error message:

Unable to connect to server '192.xxx.xxx.xxx'.
The connection was refused.
Check that XenServer is configured correctly on '192.xxx.xxx.xxx'.

When I run XenCenter on another PC, it automatically disconnects from the same server after 10-15 seconds every time I connect.

Comment: Can you access the management interface IP over SSH? If you can get a shell, would you mind adding the configuration of iptables to this question please?

Comment: It looks to be a network problem, please check your network,firewall settings etc.

Comment: It was problem with ip conflicts. Now resolved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem happened due to ip conflicts.
Resolved the issue by correcting ip setting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating XenCenter to 6.1? I had this same issue before using older builds.

Comment: yeah, It was 6.2 before with same problem, so i tried 6.0.